# Generate Augmented Reality Object without tracker on mobile phone (android/ios)

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality, vuforia, metaio

I am looking in implementing Augmented Reality in mobile (android - eclipse/ ios - xcode).
The concept that I wanted to do is generate object randomly around the area.
This concept is very similar to "**iButterfly**" which is currently in appstore/playstore.

I am new in AR type of development. 
But I have gone through some research about AR. I looked into Vuforia, Metaio and also Wikitude. All I able to get are the information of creating object based on Marker/Target, Point of Interest and Location based.

I would like to ask for some pointers/opinion/information on creating object without tracker/marker?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Vuforia introduced Smart Terrain technology. In this case, the camera can build a virtual environment of the physical environment. You can then augment in the space, and even build on physical objects within the space. See [Getting-Started-with-Smart-Terrain](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Getting-Started-with-Smart-Terrain) for more information.